# Laravel vue.js - Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500 (this happens to a only one API url, others are ok)

Tags: laravel, api, vue.js, axios, http-status-code-500

i'm kindof new to vue.js and i'm having CORS error with one of my API.
All API's are working perfectly but this particular api keeps giving me the following error. For some reason this only shows on production, but on my localhost it works properly.

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://website.com/api/list/items. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing). Status code: 500

**Below is a sample of my vue.js axios post request**

```
axios.post('https://website.com/api/list/items',
                    {
                            requestid: this.currentrequestid,
                            status: this.currentstatus,
                            user: this.currentpuserid,
                            ruser: this.currentruserid,
                            start: this.start,
                            take: this.take,
                            sortby: this.sortBy,
                            sortdir: this.sortdir,
                            stext: this.searchrequesttitle,
                            search: this.showclear,
                            type: this.currenttype,
                            supplier: this.currentsupplierid
                        },

                    {
                    headers: {
                        "Authorization" : "Bearer " + this.token,
                      
                    },

                }).then((response) =>{

                        if(response.data.error){
                            this.$swal({
                                title: "Not Authorized",
                                text: "Close and reselect from tedBase",
                                icon: "error",
                                showConfirmButton: false
                            })

                        } else {
                            this.items = response.data.items;
                            console.log(this.items[0]);
                            this.numresults = response.data.results;
                            this.isBusy = false;

                            if(this.items.length === 0){
                                this.$swal({
                                    title: "Ooops",
                                    text: "Nothing found for search",
                                    icon: "warning",
                                    timer: 3000,
                                    showConfirmButton: false
                                });
                            }

                        }

                        }).catch(err => {
                            this.$swal({
                                title: "System Error",
                                text: err,
                                icon: "warning",
                                showConfirmButton: false
                                })
                    })
```

> This is my config/cors.php

```
 'paths' => ['api/*', 'sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => false,

'max_age' => false,

'supports_credentials' => true
```

> HandleCors.php

```
<?php

namespace Fruitcake\Cors;

use Closure;
use Asm89\Stack\CorsService;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Http\Kernel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Events\RequestHandled;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

class HandleCors
{
    /** @var CorsService $cors */
    protected $cors;

    /** @var \Illuminate\Contracts\Container\Container $container */
    protected $container;

    public function __construct(CorsService $cors, Container $container)
    {
        $this->cors = $cors;
        $this->container = $container;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request. Based on Asm89\Stack\Cors by asm89
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return Response
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        // Check if we're dealing with CORS and if we should handle it
        if (! $this->shouldRun($request)) {
            return $next($request);
        }

        // For Preflight, return the Preflight response
        if ($this->cors->isPreflightRequest($request)) {
            $response = $this->cors->handlePreflightRequest($request);

            $this->cors->varyHeader($response, 'Access-Control-Request-Method');

            return $response;
        }


        // Handle the request
        $response = $next($request);

        if ($request->getMethod() === 'OPTIONS') {
            $this->cors->varyHeader($response, 'Access-Control-Request-Method');
        }

        return $this->addHeaders($request, $response);
    }

    /**
     * Add the headers to the Response, if they don't exist yet.
     *
     * @param Request $request
     * @param Response $response
     * @return Response
     */
    protected function addHeaders(Request $request, Response $response): Response
    {
        if (! $response->headers->has('Access-Control-Allow-Origin')) {
            // Add the CORS headers to the Response
            $response = $this->cors->addActualRequestHeaders($response, $request);
        }

        return $response;
    }

    /**
     * Add the headers to the Response, if they don't exist yet.
     *
     * @param RequestHandled $event
     * @deprecated
     */
    public function onRequestHandled(RequestHandled $event)
    {
        if ($this->shouldRun($event->request) && $this->container->make(Kernel::class)->hasMiddleware(static::class)) {
            $this->addHeaders($event->request, $event->response);
        }
    }


    /**
     * Determine if the request has a URI that should pass through the CORS flow.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function shouldRun(Request $request): bool
    {
        return $this->isMatchingPath($request);
    }

    /**
     * The the path from the config, to see if the CORS Service should run
     *
     * @param \Illuminate\Http\Request $request
     * @return bool
     */
    protected function isMatchingPath(Request $request): bool
    {
        // Get the paths from the config or the middleware
        $paths = $this->getPathsByHost($request->getHost());

        foreach ($paths as $path) {
            if ($path !== '/') {
                $path = trim($path, '/');
            }

            if ($request->fullUrlIs($path) || $request->is($path)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

    /**
     * Paths by given host or string values in config by default
     *
     * @param string $host
     * @return array
     */
    protected function getPathsByHost(string $host)
    {
        $paths = $this->container['config']->get('cors.paths', []);
        // If where are paths by given host
        if (isset($paths[$host])) {
            return $paths[$host];
        }
        // Defaults
        return array_filter($paths, function ($path) {
            return is_string($path);
        });
    }
}
```

> I also use "fruitcake/laravel-cors": "^2.0",

I've been on this for hours and i would appreciate your assistance.

I have added several headers to the request, i use fruitcake laravel package. but nothing seems to be working.

Only this url displays the CORS error, the other urls work perfectly. How is that possible?

Comment: Share your `config/cors.php` file and your routes used the `HandleCors` middleware in your route file.

Comment: What @cengsemihsahin said. Would be nice to know the domain the API is running on in production, request header for `axios.post('https://website.com/api/list/items')` and what has been put into the CORS related files.

Comment: Thanks guys I have updated thequestion by adding my HandleCors.php